# CGGradient issues with swift 3

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8

Just in the process of converting my code from swift 2.3 to 3. In the old code I created a gradient through the following code:

```
        let colours:CFArrayRef = [tColour.CGColor, bColour.CGColor]
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colours, nil)
```

When Xcode 8 converted the code it changed it to the following:

```
    let colours:CFArray = [tColour.cgColor, bColour.cgColor]
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colours, locations: nil)
```

However the code produces the following error:

> Contextual type 'CFArray' cannot be used with array literal

Can anybody suggest how to convert the code properly.

With thanks

Reza

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cast the type

```
let colours = [tColour.cgColor, bColour.cgColor] as CFArray
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colours , locations: nil)
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Swift 4

Comment: @EddieSullivan I just tested it successfully in Swift 4

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, make sure you've created an array of `CGColor` objects. If you're starting with `UIColor` objects, just use the `cgColor` property like in the example. This tripped me up for a minute—since you're casting to CFArray you won't get a warning about them being the wrong type.

Comment: @vadian The above code doesn't work. I get an error at 'locations' : 'nil' cannot be assigned to type '[CGFloat]'. Is it due to Swift 5?